# RubyMine and special characters, show ? when outputting results

Tags: character-encoding, cucumber, rubymine

Update-edit: Here is the requested information.

Used both Rubymine 3.2.4 and the EAP version (113.2). 
JRuby: 1.6.6-p357
Windows 7 64 bit

I've double checked the UTF8 config, in the IDE: File -> Settings -> General, and in the file located in ....RubyMine40\config\options\encoding.xml, both are set to UTF-8.
I have tried to set #encoding: utf-8 in my .feature file, but it still shows my special chars (æøå) as ?. Actually, it won't even run the test if I use these characters in the code under

```
Feature: This is some test      # Feature = Egenskap in norwegian
```

I opened the .feature file that I created in RubyMine 4.0 (EAP) in Notepad++, and it says its coded in ANSI as UTF-8.

## The question

I have a problem with special characters, in my case, æ ø å. I use RubymMine to develop cucumber tests. My IDE encoding is set to use UTF-8.

The problem is, that when I run the tests in my RubyMine, the console simply replace my special chars (æøå) with ?, which is annoying, and this also happens when I do a HTML export of the tests. I can write the .feature files in my langauge no problem,using #language: no comment at the top of feature file. It only gets messy when Rubymine outputs to console, and export the results.

Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to solve it? Or can just point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please specify your OS and Ruby/RubyMine versions, double check the encoding in the IDE settings (global and per directory/file). Verify that files are actually saved in the specified encoding. If the issue remains, please share a sample project to reproduce it. Does the problem remain in 4.0 beta from http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP? Are you sure you don't need to put `#encoding: utf-8` in the beginning of your files?

Comment: Thank you CrazyCoder, I will provide all those details after this meeting. For now, I opened the files in Notepad++, to see that it is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM. Trying to convert this to plain UTF-8 caused the cucumber test to not be run. Will provide more details soon.

Comment: @CrazyCoder How do you want me to show you a sample project?

Comment: Prepare an isolated sample project and share it via Dropbox or send to JetBrains support. Did you try it with Ruby 1.9.3? The problem could be specific to JRuby.

Comment: This appears to still affect RubyMine 5 (seeing it with Chinese characters in 5.0.2) and Ruby 1.9.3 (MRI).